# What are the algorithms used in Facebook's Diem algorithm?

Tags: hash, implementation, cryptocurrency

Facebook plan a new cryptocurrency release called [Diem](https://github.com/diem/diem). What algorithms are used? What output size is used for the hash function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all the useful informations are [here](http://%20https://github.com/diem/diem/tree/main/crypto/crypto).

Citation :
"SHA-3 as the main hash function. It is standardized in FIPS 202. It is based on the tiny_keccak library.

HKDF: HMAC-based Extract-and-Expand Key Derivation Function (HKDF) based on RFC 5869. It is used to generate keys from a salt (optional), seed, and application-info (optional).
traits.rs introduces new abstractions for the crypto API.

Ed25519 performs signatures using the new API design based on ed25519-dalek library with additional security checks (e.g. for malleability).

X25519 to perform key exchanges. It is used to secure communications between validators via the Noise Protocol Framework. It is based on the x25519-dalek library."

Comment: According to https://github.com/diem/diem/blob/main/crypto/crypto/src/hash.rs the hash length is $256$ bits.